# Simple MATLAB Script

Tags: arrays, matlab, fft

I have conducted 400 experiments and got several data. So I am writing a code that allows me to read all the files using MATLAB, analyze it and store the results in an array. Otherwise I would have to do them individually which would take forever.

**Code:**

```
clear
clc
close all

myfolder='C:\Users\Surface\Desktop\New_folder\';
filepattern=fullfile(myfolder,'.txt');
thefiles=dir(filepattern);

for i=1:length(thefiles)
    baseFileName=thefiles(i).name;
    fullFileName=fullfile(myfolder,baseFileName);
    fprintf(1,'Now reading %s\n',fullFileName);
    load(fullFileName);    
    Fs=500; % Samping frequency

    for i=1:n        
        A=Listing(i).name;       
        [t,X,Xrms(i)]=process_data(Listing(i).name);        
    end

    % Extract the data for the time period of [ts tf]    
    ts=0;    
    tf=3;    
    t=t(ts*Fs+1:tf*Fs+1);
    X=X(ts*Fs+1:tf*Fs+1);    
end

% FFT analysis to see the natural frequency
fftplot(1/Fs,X);

% Find the damping ratio
[zeta zeta_m]=finddamping(t,X)
```

I was wondering where I went wrong.

Comment: See how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: What's wrong about it?